# Changing an Object's properties in another class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oop, stack-overflow

I'm trying to change an Object's properties from another class, like so.

abilities.cs (class)

```
        public static void hideAllButtons()
        {
            frmFight fight = new frmFight();
            fight.btnAbility1.Visible = false;
            fight.btnAbility2.Visible = false;
            fight.btnAbility3.Visible = false;
            fight.btnAbility4.Visible = false;
            fight.btnAbility5.Visible = false;
            fight.btnAbility6.Visible = false;
            vars.buttonsVisible = false;
        }
```

I'm trying to use the method from the previous class to change the object's properties in the following Form;

frmFight.cs (form)

```
        private void btnAbility1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abilities.hideAllButtons();
            btnAbilities.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I've tried everything in my knowledge and understanding, and a lot of looking up on the internet. I've tried making the objects static, public, creating the object within the class. But nothing works. Usually I get StackOverFlow errors.

I'm pretty new to OOP, too, but I'm not an idiot so don't think to go too 'lightly' on me with a possible fix, or cause, of my problem - if you understand, that is.

Comment: Hi Brian. Can you explain why you're instantiating a new instance of frmFight in hideAllButtons()?

Comment: Hey. Yeah, the btnAbilityX objects were made on the frmFight form. So don't I have to create a new instance of them in the abilities class for them to be reffered to?

Comment: in that case there is no need to create a new instance of frmFight. I see a couple good solutions below so I won't post an answer. Good luck in OOP!

Comment: Thank you! First question, and quick response. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `hideAllButtons` is static so should have a Form argument.

```
 public static void hideAllButtons(frmFight fight)
 {
  fight.btnAbility1.Visible = false;
  fight.btnAbility2.Visible = false;
  fight.btnAbility3.Visible = false;
  fight.btnAbility4.Visible = false;
  fight.btnAbility5.Visible = false;
  fight.btnAbility6.Visible = false;
  //vars.buttonsVisible = false; // What about this???
 }
```

and call this method in click handler,

```
hideAllButtons(this);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Would it be any trouble for you to tell me why I was wrong, and what this does exactly? If not, then that's not a problem! Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: You were creating a new instance of frmFight and hiding the buttons on that one, but not changing the buttons on the original form.  This second form would remain hidden until it is eventually deleted by the garbage collector.  This code passes the frmFight object to the hideAllButtons method, so the changes are done on the visible form.

Answer (score 2):

This really wont work because your controls is on your frmFight.

You need to do is place

```
 private void hideAllButtons()
    {
        btnAbility1.Visible = false;
        btnAbility2.Visible = false;
        btnAbility3.Visible = false;
        btnAbility4.Visible = false;
        btnAbility5.Visible = false;
        btnAbility6.Visible = false;
        vars.buttonsVisible = false;
    }
```

on your frmFight.cs (form) as private method and just call it on your button click to make it simpler.

```
    private void btnAbility1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hideAllButtons();
        btnAbilities.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Regards